# loading navbar for the whole site, how should i deal with the links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have just started this small project for a website and I thought i should use only one menu bar for the whole site, since it's kinda tedious to have to change all the links for all the pages in the menu bar.

I have found the following code for loading my menu bar:

```
<div id="nav-placeholder"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbar.html");
  });
</script>
```

It works fine and I do get my menu, however I find that the links basically work the same as if I just had the menu on the page instead of loading it.

So for example if I am on the root directory everything loads fine, but as soon as I move up one directory the links wont work anymore.

I know this can be fixed by simply changing them, but then I would have to make more than a couple of navbars for the whole site?

Any fix around this?, hope you guys get my idea, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Change the links so they start relative to the root folder of the domain, eg. `/foo.html`, `/links/bar.html` etc. Also note that Server Side Includes are much better suited for including template content in to a page that JS, as JS will have a FOUC while the AJAX request completes.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Rory.  such a small thing, hahah really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using anything that can dynamically create pages on the fly like ASP or PHP then you could make a separate page with just the menu in and include it in each page that needs it. For example:

ASP:

```
<!-- #Include virtual="menu.aspx" -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php include 'menu.php';?>
```